# Catalina Keeps Deleting Documents Symbolic Link

Tags: catalina

I have a symbolic link from ~/Documents to ~/Dropbox/MyDocuments.

However I noticed that Catalina from time to time deletes my symbolic link and replaces it with a new Documents folder. I think its happening at a reboot but may happen at other times as well. Any way to prevent this

Comment: Are you using iCloud Drive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found a workaround for this that I got from the Dropbox forum. As for many years, I 've been syncing my Desktop using Dropbox. However, because of the new layer of security in Catalina, it deletes the folder.

Here is a solution that I did it and it is fine for me now.

> After creating the symlink to my Dropbox desktop folder, I locked the
>   link file by displaying its info and checking the 'Locked' checkbox.
>   That seems to do the trick. I checked that I can still write and save
>   to my desktop.

Link: [Dropbox Symlinks](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Files-folders/Best-practices-for-using-symlinks-symbolic-links/m-p/371557/highlight/true#M131468)

Answer (score 2):

Locking the symlink as `root`, as others have mentioned, is the answer. This can all be done from a script so you don't have to enable and log into the `root` account.

Here is a simple script I wrote that needs to be run as `root` (with `sudo`) that takes two arguments:

1. Short username
2. Name of your OneDrive folder (Just `OneDrive` for personal OneDrive accounts)

This script will:

1. Create a `Desktop` and `Documents` folder in the specified `OneDrive` folder
2. Copy all items from your existing `Desktop` and `Documents` folders into OneDrive using `rsync`
3. Delete your `Desktop` and `Documents` folders
4. Symlink `Desktop` and `Documents` to OneDrive
5. Lock the symlinks themselves so they aren't deleted on login/reboot

Warning:

**This script doesn't do any error checking or folder existence verification. It might delete all of your files. Make sure you have a backup.**

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $# -lt 2 ]] ; then
    echo "Scipt requires two arguments:"
    echo "Argument 1. Short username"
    echo "Argument 2. Name of OneDrive folder"
    exit 1
fi

shortname=$1
onedrive=$2

#########
# DESKTOP
#########

# Make Desktop folder in OneDrive
mkdir -p "/Users/$shortname/$onedrive/Desktop"

# Copy all files from existing Desktop folder to OneDrive Desktop folder
rsync -havux --progress --stats "/Users/$shortname/Desktop" "/Users/$shortname/$onedrive/Desktop"

# Remove existing Desktop folder
rm -rf "/Users/$shortname/Desktop"

# Create symlink to Desktop folder in OneDrive
ln -s "/Users/$shortname/$onedrive/Desktop" "/Users/$shortname/Desktop"

# Set the symlink itself (-h flag) to system locked. (User locked would be uchg)
chflags -h schg "/Users/$shortname/Desktop"

###########
# DOCUMENTS
###########

# Make Documents folder in OneDrive
mkdir -p "/Users/$shortname/$onedrive/Documents"

# Copy all files from existing Documents folder to OneDrive Documents folder
rsync -havux --progress --stats "/Users/$shortname/Documents" "/Users/$shortname/$onedrive/Documents"

# Remove existing Documents folder
rm -rf "/Users/$shortname/Documents"

# Create symlink to Documents folder in OneDrive
ln -s "/Users/$shortname/$onedrive/Documents" "/Users/$shortname/Documents"

# Set the symlink itself (-h flag) to system locked. (User locked would be uchg)
chflags -h schg "/Users/$shortname/Documents"
```

Comment: tldr `chflags -h schg`. Very helpful though because the GUI checkbox itself was greyed out, so I had to use this CLI

Comment: FYI, OneDrive is adding built-in known-folder-move (KFM). It is currently in preview. This should replace this hacky method. See: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-onedrive-blog/apple-silicon-support-in-ga-and-kfm-for-macos-in-public-preview/ba-p/3215671

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with the Desktop folder. I would do this :

```
$ sudo rm -Rf ~/Desktop
$ sudo ln -s ~/Dropbox/Desktop ~/Desktop
```

And the symlink was replaced by a new folder at the next reboot.

---

As other users experimented ([here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250723356?answerId=251515202022#251515202022) and [here](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Files-folders/Best-practices-for-using-symlinks-symbolic-links/m-p/372121/highlight/true#M131698)), it turns out we can not lock a symlink anymore in macOS, the option is greyed out.

I found 2 solutions to this issue :

- Lock the parent folder (your home folder, `/Users/you/`) but this will prevent you from adding/deleting files there ([source](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Files-folders/Best-practices-for-using-symlinks-symbolic-links/m-p/384267/highlight/true#M138100))
- Disable completely iCloud Drive in `System Preferences > Apple ID` (Keeping it enabled with "Desktop & Documents Folders" uncheck does not do the trick) [image]

Answer (score 0):

I have another solution to overcome the problem of greyed locked checkbox:

1. `sudo rm -Rf ~/Desktop`
2. `sudo ln -s ~/Dropbox/Desktop ~/Downloads/Desktop`
3. Using the Finder, select `~/Downloads/Desktop` icon, select `Get info` from `File` menu, and click the `Locked` checkbox (it is not greyed out!).
4. Using the Finder, copy `~/Downloads/Desktop` icon to `~/` (home) folder.
5. Delete `~/Downloads/Desktop` symlink.

You can use another folder instead of `~/Downloads`. And you can do the same to have a `Documents` symlink pointing to `~/Dropbox/Documents`.